# On zoom change, features getting disappear in openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I am having some features on map, after I move them, using

```
var point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(newlon, newlat);
point.transform(epsg4326, projectTo);
VectorLayer.features[0].geometry.move(point);
```

features are being shown on new location as expected but as soon as I change the zoom level, features are getting disappear. Anyone has any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question, but I have the same issue and I solved increasing the `renderBuffer` value of the `VectorLayer`.

According to the [docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html):

> renderBuffer -    number (defaults to 100)
>
> The buffer in pixels around the viewport extent used by the renderer
> when getting features from the vector source for the rendering or
> hit-detection. Recommended value: the size of the largest symbol, line
> width or label.

Answer (score 0):

Set OpenLayers.Renderer.SVG.prototype.MAX_PIXEL = Number.MAX_VALUE in a script tag after loading OpenLayers.js. But be warned that this may freeze older browsers (e.g. Firefox 2.x).

Found at: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-dev/2010-July/006258.html

Resource:  https://github.com/openlayers/ol2/issues/668